Automatically running javascript Excel add-in code without manual approval
I want to implement a javascript add-in for Excel that automatically runs when I open any Excel file on my computer, without the need of the user to manually activate it and without opening any right pane, meaning that it will run in the background
I read some of the posts that mentioned that this is not possible:
Automatically load and start runtime of Office-js add-ins for all documents
Run code automatically in the background as soon as Office JS add-in is sideloaded in Office Client
However I saw some documentation like using Office.onReady or Office.initialize that says that I can run my code once opening the file.
I just wanted to know if that is possible or not
If not - can I implement such a method using COM add-in?
Thanks
